# How to replace all squared brackets and commas using regex in java?

Tags: java, regex

Having next line:

```
String filtered = data.replaceAll("//[ /,]"," ");
```

where **data** is like to ["blahblah","blahblah"], but nothing good happens

How to remove all unnecessary symbols and get filtered like "blablah blahblah"?

Comment: Items such as square brackets are reserved delimiters and as such will need escaping with the backslash. Your regex probably (I've not tested it) will be: //\[ /,\]. Use G Skinner's online regex to test it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to have a space between words you need to replace , to " ":

```
String filtered = data.replaceAll("\\[|\\]|\"","");
filtered = filtered.replaceAll(","," ");
```

Now the output is "blahblah blahblah"

Answer (score 7):

Use this pattern:

```
"\\W+"
```

#### [Online Demo](https://regex101.com/r/lY9iT3/2)

- `"` delimiter
- `\` escapes `\`
- `\W+` match one or more non-word character(s)

---

**Full code:**

```
String filtered = data.replaceAll("\\W+","");
```